# How to add code folding for codeeditor example of pyside6?

Tags: pyside6, code-editor

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qtforpython-6.2/examples/example_widgets__codeeditor.html

I'm trying to add a code folding area to right of line number area for brace pairs if pairs located at different lines. How to implement it? thank you.

Comment: You can change the visibility of QTextBlocks using [`setVisible()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextblock.html#setVisible).

Comment: can you give me a example code?